# Returning an array to React component from fetch call in Redux

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, fetch, redux-thunk

I'm having trouble returning an array to my React component from a fetch call from my Express server, that I set up in Redux.

I'm trying to just return the vitamins array from this json from Express:

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   vitamins: [
    {
       name: "Vitamin B2"
    }
   ],
   minerals: [
   {
      name: "Zinc"
   }
   ]});
 });
```

This is the fetch call and FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS action in my actions.js.

```
 export function fetchVitamins() {
   return dispatch => {
     return fetch("/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(micros => {
        dispatch(fetchVitaminsSuccess(micros.vitamins));
        return micros.vitamins;
    })
  };
 }

 export const FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS';

 export const fetchVitaminsSuccess = vitamins => ({
    type: FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS,
    payload: { vitamins }
 });
```

This is my reducers.js where i'm trying to set the state to "micros.vitamins".

```
 const initialState = {
   micros: [],
 };

 function vitaminReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS:
    return {
       ...state.vitamins,
       micros: action.payload
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

This is my React component Vitamins.js where I'm importing fetchVitamins() and trying to pass the names of each vitamins to a menu dropdown in an option tag.

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchVitamins();
}

renderData() {
   const { vitamins } = this.state.micros;
   return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
      return (
        <option value={micro.value} key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
      )
   })
 } 

render() {
  return (
    <select value={this.props.value}>
      {this.renderData()}
    </select>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   micros: state.vitamins,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchVitamins })(Vitamins);
```

Right now I get back the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'micros' of null", highlighting over my renderData() function.

Comment: you mean `this.props.micros` right? `this.state` refers to component state. that's why the function is called "map state to PROPS"

Comment: by the way.. your express function, the `router.get` call. is the code you posted exactly what your route looks like? or are you missing some code

Comment: Right, thank you. I now get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'vitamins' of undefined`. The `router.get` code is all there, i just didn't include the router and express calls at the top. The fetch call works, I've already tested that.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
const { vitamins } = this.props.micros;
```

because you pass `micros` as props from redux. While you tried to access it from the state (which I guess was not initialized that's why it's null).

Another thing, you pass Object in payload:

```
export const fetchVitaminsSuccess = vitamins => ({
  type: FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { vitamins }
});
```

and set it as `micros` in your reducer:

```
switch(action.type) {
case FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS:
return {
   ...state.vitamins,
   micros: action.payload
};
```

However, your `micros` are initially an array which may lead to unexpected errors. Maybe you should change your initial state to something resembling the response like:

```
const initialState = {
  micros: {
    vitamins: []
  },
};
```

This way `const { vitamins } = this.state.micros;` will always return some array - before and after the response.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I made it this.props.micros, but now I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'vitamins' of undefined`.

Comment: @bigjohnjr see the edit, especially about setting initial state.

Comment: error could be coming from ajax call. I assumed OPs `router.get` code was not his entire code, considering the syntax error, but it's possible the server is not actually responding with anything

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk Well when I had this in my localState it was `state = micros: []`, and then I set the state in `componentDidMount()` where the `fetch` call was like `.then(micros => { this.setState({ micros: micros.vitamins })}`. I'm basically trying to figure out how to do that same thing with actions and reducers.